# Venmo iOS SDK pod integration issues

Tags: ios, linker-errors, venmo

I am trying to integrate the [Venmo iOS SDK](https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk) but am having problems even importing it into my project. Upon installing the pod, here is my error:

[image: error1]

The SDK mentions that there may be issues integrating Venmo with Parse, so I followed their redirect link and added the following [recommended Other Linker Flags](https://gist.github.com/diogeneshamilton/6c1585280da8de16560d):

```
-force_load
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-Venmo-iOS-SDK.a 
-force_load
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-VENCore.a
```

Doing so produced this error:

[image]

There is very little information on the web or in their docs about these issues. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried 1) clearing your derived data folder, 2) Clean your project and then RUN ?

Comment: Make sure you open the workspace and not the project when using Cocoapods.

Comment: @PiyushSharma yes, errors still occur.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `use_frameworks!` to my Podfile.